# After disabling object cache in W3 Total cache, admin backend post editing is not working

Tags: wordpress, admin, backend, w3-total-cache

I disabled object cache in W3 Total Cache plugin.
After that , in admin dashboard, post editing is not working. Please help.

Comment: I'm more or less with the same problem. In my case, it was the page editing, not the post editing page (it gives an error 503). I think it was because I cached the pages (but not the posts). Tried to disable it (it is hard to disable it because it leaves lots of trash inside the site folders... I followed this link steps, but I was not able to fix the problem, so I'll not post it as an answer, but if you want to give it a try. Maybe you have more luck than me!
https://journalxtra.com/wordpress/uninstall-w3-total-cache-proper/